# need to pass an effect via props or force component reload from outside the root component in preact/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, preact

I have a situation that an item outside the component might influence the item in the backend. ex: change the value of one of the properties that are persisted, let's say the item status moves from Pending to Completed.

I know when it happens but since it is outside of a component I need to tell to the component that it is out of sync and re-fetch the data. But from outside. I know you can pass props calling the render method again. But the problem is I have a reducer and the state will pick up the last state and if I use an prop to trigger an effect I get into a loop.

Here is what I did:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.effect && !state.effect) { //this runs when the prop changes
      return dispatch({ type: props.effect, });
    }
    if (state.effect) { // but then I get here and then back up and so on
      return ModelEffect[state.effect](state?.data?.item)}, [state.status, state.effect, props.effect,]);
```

In short since I can't get rid of the prop the I get the first one then the second and so on in an infinite loop.

I render the root component passing the id:

```
render(html`<${Panel} id=${id}/>`,
            document.getElementById('Panel'));
```

Then the idea was that I could do this to sync it:

```
render(html`<${Panel} id=${id} effect="RELOAD"/>`,
                document.getElementById('Panel'));
```

any better ways to solve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by passing the initialized dispatch function to a global.

```
function Panel (props) {
//...
const [state, dispatch,] = useReducer(RequestReducer, initialData);
//...
useEffect(() => {
//...
window.GlobalDispatch = dispatch;
//...
}, [state.status, state.effect,]);
```

with that I can do:

```
window.GlobalDispatch({type:'RELOAD'});
```